# Python: How to send list from one method back to another?

Tags: python, loops, class, static-methods

I hope I can describe this problem easily enough to be understood. My Python/CS education is not formal and I'm not always sure about my terminology. Bear with me and give me some grace, please.

I have a Class with at least two static methods. One method (A) calls the other (B) on a loop. Inside B, I append elements to a list if certain requirements are met. I want to share this list with the user (this is a command line tool). However, with how things are designed right now I am sharing the list one element on a time per loop. I am not sure how to populate this list fully and get it back to Method A and then share it with the user.  If I make the list a constant outside of the methods then method B is unable to see it (??) and append to it. :(

```
helperclass.py

class HelperClass(object)
    def __init__(self)

    # { methods-n-code-here}

myclass.py
import helperclass

class MyClass(HelperClass)
    @staticmethod
    GenerateFoo(params1, params2, params3):
        # generate some executable scripts
        for x in projects:
            # do stuff
            MyClass.CreateBar(params1, params2, params3)

            for y in other:
                # do stuff

        return xyz

    @staticmethod
    CreateBar(params1, params2, params3):
        # do stuff
        # do more stuff
        myList = []
        for x in list
            if z.isThatThing():
                ThatThing = click.confirm(# user prompt: Y/N)
                # do this  
                if not ThatThing:
                    myList.append(foobar)

                # more stuff
            # more stuff
        if len(myList) > 0:
            for a in myList:
                print(a)
```

Anyway, what is it that I do not understand? :(

Comment: There's no A or B in your code, just `GenerateFoo` and `CreateBar`, only one of which returns anything.  If you're going to provide pseudocode and describe it, the description needs to match the pseudocode -- but it would be much better to provide actual (runnable) code so other people can just run it instead of trying to imagine what it does based on your description.  :)

Comment: @Samwise I understand; I will try to do that for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add `return myList` at the end of CreateBar() function so that you can get back the list inside the for loop of GenerateFoo() function. And then if you want to concatenate the lists then you can declear a new empty list `list = []` and then inside for loop of GenerateFoo() you can write `myList = MyClass.CreateBar(params1, params2, params3)` to store the list in myList and again to concatenate use `list.extend(myList)`. At the end of GenerateFoo() return the concatenated list using `return list`.

I have edited your example code below and put `###` to new and modified lines to make it easier to find them.

helperclass.py:

```
    class HelperClass(object)
        def __init__(self)
    
        # { methods-n-code-here}
    
    myclass.py
    import helperclass
    
    class MyClass(HelperClass)
        @staticmethod
        GenerateFoo(params1, params2, params3):
            # generate some executable scripts
            list = []                        ###
            for x in projects:
                # do stuff
                myList = MyClass.CreateBar(params1, params2, params3) ###
                list.extend(myList)          ###
                for y in other:
                    # do stuff
    
            return list                      ###
    
        @staticmethod
        CreateBar(params1, params2, params3):
            # do stuff
            # do more stuff
            myList = []
            for x in list
                if z.isThatThing():
                    ThatThing = click.confirm(# user prompt: Y/N)
                    # do this  
                    if not ThatThing:
                        myList.append(foobar)
            return myList                     ###
```

Comment: The flow makes sense. Thank you for explaining and even the potential code. Now I know how to do this and you solved my problem :)